# Azure storage logs not being purged

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my storage account Diagnostics settings I have "Retention (days)" set to 30.  When I use the Azure Storage Explorer to check the `$logs` container, I can still see all the logs since I created my storage account, more than 60 days ago.

My understanding of the Retention setting was that Azure would purge the `$logs` container of anything older than the specified number of days.  Did I misunderstand, or is something amiss?

Comment: Which Retention setting are you looking at?  There is one for Monitoring which will control the $Metrics tables, and one for Logging which will control the $logs container.

Comment: @kwill I'm using the Preview portal, where monitoring and logging are both configured under the Diagnostics blade.  There's only one retention setting there, which apparently only applies to monitoring.

Comment: It's a long shot 8 years later, but @BenV did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DisplayName Unfortunately, my memory of this issue, unlike my logs apparently, has been purged :(.  Sorry for being [that guy](https://xkcd.com/979/)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you set the retention policy under logging for the object and type of requests, the log entries will be deleted after number of days that you set in the policy.  See more details under "How to: Configure Logging" section in the following documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/.

Can you check and make sure that the entries that were left undeleted are for the objects and requests that you did not set retention policy?

Comment: See my comment above.  Apparently setting the retention period in the preview portal only applies to monitoring?

Comment: I will investigate and get back to you on this.

Comment: Can you email your storage account name to ascl@microsoft.com so that we can further investigate?