# Azure App Service "Application Logging (Blob)" does not delete logs after specified Retention Period

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-appservice

I've configured the "Application Logging (Blob)" for my Azure App Service to have a Retention Period of 1 day:

[image]

However, the logs are not purged after the Retention Period.

What am I missing? It seems like it should be straight forward, but there is very little documentation.

My problem appears to be the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676602/azure-storage-logs-not-being-purged), but there is no accepted answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Upvoted. I'm also curious about this.